# No inputstream constructor for JSONTokener

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to parse a JSON from an InputStream in Android Studio.

I have this code:

```
InputStream body = session.getInputStream();
JSONTokener t = new JSONTokener(body);
```

It doesn't work, because it says JSONTokener has no InputStream constructor.
Docs say otherwise: https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONTokener.html

I assume it uses a wrong version, so I tried adding this to my build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'org.json:json:20190722'
```

But it didn't work. Any idea how can I solve it?